# switch all pages to new domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all my website traffic at mydomain.com to mynewdomain.net.

Both sites have exactly same structure.

All pages in html, php, css, images, etc of  mydomain.com shoud be redirected to mynewdomain.net

For example: mydomain.com/assets/abc.php should become mynewdomain.net/assets/abc.php

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewdomain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```